Batch and Epoch training metrics for transformers Trainer
There are several ways to get metrics for transformers.Trainer but only for the evaluation and not for the training. I read and found answers scattered in different posts such as this post.
But nowhere did I find how to get metrics for an epoch (loss, accuracy, recall, precision, f1)**
I provide the solution in the first answer.
Let me know if there are some ways to optimize or errors in the code, I'll be happy to hear them.

Here is a way, I also provide a way to get the metrics for each batch:
Summary:

Custom the Trainer class to store the pred., labels and loss.
Override computer_loss() function within the Custom Trainer Class to get the pred., labels and loss at the end of each batch.
Create a CustomCallback Class + Custom the on_epoch_end() function in that Class to get, concat., calculate and return the metrics (I used loss, acc, recall, prec. and f1)
Add the CustomCallBack after defining the trainer in your training function.

Extensive and Code:
Notes: In my case I'm plotting directly using wandb instead of returning the values + My classification is binary, I'm not sure if something needs to be changed for multiclass prediction + I'm running on a single GPU.
Steps 1 and 2:
CustomTrainer(transformers.Trainer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.epoch_predictions = []
        self.epoch_labels = []
        self.epoch_loss = []

    def compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs=False):
        """
        MAX: Subclassed to compute training accuracy.

        How the loss is computed by Trainer. By default, all models return the loss in
        the first element.

        Subclass and override for custom behavior.
        """
        if self.label_smoother is not None and "labels" in inputs:
            labels = inputs.pop("labels")
        else:
            labels = None
        outputs = model(**inputs)

        if "labels" in inputs:
            preds = outputs.logits.detach()

            # Log accuracy
            acc = (
                (preds.argmax(axis=1) == inputs["labels"])
                .type(torch.float)
                .mean()
                .item()
            )
            # Uncomment it if you want to plot the batch accuracy
            # wandb.log({"batch_accuracy": acc})  # Log accuracy

            # Store predictions and labels for epoch-level metrics
            self.epoch_predictions.append(preds.cpu().numpy())
            self.epoch_labels.append(inputs["labels"].cpu().numpy())

        # Save past state if it exists
        if self.args.past_index >= 0:
            self._past = outputs[self.args.past_index]

        if labels is not None:
            loss = self.label_smoother(outputs, labels)
        else:
            loss = outputs["loss"] if isinstance(outputs, dict) else outputs[0]
            # Uncomment it if you want to plot the batch loss
            # wandb.log({"batch_loss": loss})
            self.epoch_loss.append(loss.item())  # Store loss for epoch-level metrics

        return (loss, outputs) if return_outputs else loss

Step 3:
class CustomCallback(TrainerCallback):

    def __init__(self, trainer) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._trainer = trainer

    def on_epoch_end(self, args, state, control, **kwargs):
        # Aggregate predictions and labels for the entire epoch
        epoch_predictions = np.concatenate(self._trainer.epoch_predictions)
        epoch_labels = np.concatenate(self._trainer.epoch_labels)

        # Compute accuracy
        accuracy = np.mean(epoch_predictions.argmax(axis=1) == epoch_labels)

        # Compute mean loss
        mean_loss = np.mean(self._trainer.epoch_loss)

        # Compute precision, recall, and F1-score
        precision, recall, f1, _ = precision_recall_fscore_support(
            epoch_labels, epoch_predictions.argmax(axis=1), average="weighted"
        )

        # Log epoch-level metrics
        wandb.log({"epoch_accuracy": accuracy, "epoch_loss": mean_loss})
        wandb.log({"precision": precision, "recall": recall, "f1": f1})

        # Clear stored predictions, labels, and loss for the next epoch
        self._trainer.epoch_predictions = []
        self._trainer.epoch_labels = []
        self._trainer.epoch_loss = []
        return None

Step 4:
...
    trainer = CustomTrainer(model=model,
                            tokenizer=tokenizer,
                            args=training_args,
                            compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
                            train_dataset=train_dataset,
                            eval_dataset=val_dataset,
                            data_collator=data_collator)

    trainer.add_callback(CustomCallback(trainer))
    trainer.train()
...


thank you for your excellent work, the calculation of your metrics works in muticlass

Happy to hear it helped :D
